# In Next.js, I can't get the mongoDB document on the same line of my query?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, next.js, promise

I tried the following on my Next.js backend, and I have MongoDB collection named "users". I want to find the user that has the maximum id.

```
const max_id = await users.find({}).sort({"id":-1}).limit(1).toArray()[0]["id"]
```

I get the error of `unhandledRejection: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')` which indicates this entire statement returns none.

However, if I do the following in two lines, everything works as intended:

```
const newest_user = await users.find({}).sort({"id":-1}).limit(1).toArray();
const max_id = newest_user[0]["id"];
```

in my first example that doesn't work, is that because **users.find({}).sort({"id":-1}).limit(1).toArray()** is a promise, it will take time to resolve. But before the promise resolves, the promise's value is undefined, and **undefined[0]["id"]** will throw an error.

Please correct me.

Comment: since it is `toArray()` that returns the Promise, you want to await that Promise - that's where the so called "grouping operator" `(....)` comes in handy ... `const max_id = (await users.find({}).sort({"id":-1}).limit(1).toArray())[0]["id"]` - personally, I'd use the 2 line code that is more readable

Comment: toArray returns the promise? Not the limit? I thought limit returns the result, and toArray turns it into an array? @JaromandaX

Comment: well, yes, according to the code that works -  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ now if `users.find({}).sort({"id":-1}).limit(1).toArray()` then it isn't `undefined` ... it's a Promise ... and a promise doesn't have a `[0]` property, so it's `users.find({}).sort({"id":-1}).limit(1).toArray()[0]` that's undefined ... not `users.find({}).sort({"id":-1}).limit(1).toArray()`